# Qt - Receive input events from an external touchpad

Tags: c++, qt

I have access to an external touchpad , a prototype version. It has a primitive usb driver which, when connected to a pc, lets me read the touch co-ordinates. It supports multitouch, upto 10 points.

Now , how do I integrate this with Qt to accept these co-ordinates as input ? What would I need to change ?

For example, control the dials in the following example using the touchpad : http://apidocs.meego.com/1.0/qt4.7/multitouch-dials.html

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why this had raiting of -2??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt represent touch events as `QTouchEvent`. No surprise, really. Just create and post those in response to your external touchpad inputs.